# Cannot Import Name (model)

Tags: python, django, url, importerror

I am getting the error message above, more specifically "ImportError at /ops_page/create" "cannot import name ops_page." Basically, I have an app titled "ops_page" and I cannot seem to get the newly created url, "/ops_page/create" which should contain a form corresponding to the model within "ops_page." I have looked at similar threads, and have tried deleting .pyc files in the ops_page app as well as the root directory, as well as deleting the sqlite db and re-syncing/migrating. Any idea what the issue might be here?

My base urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    .
    .
    url(r'^ops_page/', include('ops_page.urls')),
    .
    .
)
```

My ops_page urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^create/$', 'ops_page.views.create'),
)
```

My ops_page models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
import os.path



class OpsPageInfo(models.Model):
        campaign_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True)
        campaign_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/opspage_pics")
        description_header = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
        campaign_description = models.CharField(max_length=600, blank=True)
        goal = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
        perk_header1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
        perk_description1 = models.CharField(max_length=600, blank=True)


        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.campaign_name
```

My ops_page views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from ops_page.models import OpsPageInfo
from django.http import HttpResponse
from forms import OpsPageForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


def create(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = OpsPageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()


            return HttpResponseRedirect('/artist_donation/')

    else:
        form = OpsPageForm()

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = form

    return render_to_response('create_opspage.html', args)
```

My ops_page forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from models import ops_page


class OpsPageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ops_page
```

The create_opspage.html form:

```
            {% block content %}
            <form action="/ops_page/create/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                <ul>
                {{ form.as_ul }}
                </ul>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Ops Page">
            </form>
            {% endblock %}
```

And lastly, the traceback for my error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ops_page/create

Django Version: 1.7.5
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'band',
 'friend',
 'registration',
 'music',
 'audiofield',
 'user_profile',
 'social.apps.django_app.default',
 'directory',
 'youtube_urls',
 'ops_page')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'audiofield.middleware.threadlocals.ThreadLocals')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  87.                 response = middleware_method(request)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.5-py2.7.egg/django/middleware/common.py" in process_request
  73.                     urlresolvers.is_valid_path("%s/" % request.path_info, urlconf)):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in is_valid_path
  619.         resolve(path, urlconf)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  494.     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  345.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  345.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  224.             return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
  231.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.5-py2.7.egg/django/utils/lru_cache.py" in wrapper
  101.                     result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  97.             mod = import_module(mod_name)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "/Users/sethjones/Desktop/atmos_v6/ops_page/views.py" in <module>
  4. from forms import OpsPageForm
File "/Users/sethjones/Desktop/atmos_v6/ops_page/forms.py" in <module>
  2. from models import ops_page

Exception Type: ImportError at /ops_page/create
Exception Value: cannot import name ops_page
```

I am relatively new to django, so it could be an error in my syntax or I didn't map things correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The issue lies in your `forms.py`.

```
from models import ops_page
```

should be replaced with

```
from ops_page.models import OpsPageInfo
```

And in your `OpsPageForm`'s `Meta` class, set `model` to `OpsPageInfo`.

You have another import issue in `views.py`, replace

```
from forms import OpsPageForm
```

by

```
from opt_page.forms import OpsPageForm
```

Answer (score 3):

The line that matters:

```
File "/Users/sethjones/Desktop/atmos_v6/ops_page/forms.py" in <module>
  2. from models import ops_page
```

It's telling you that the import isn't right. Now, if you go check on your `forms.py` file, you will see the line `from models import ops_page` which indeed is wrong. It should be `from models import OpsPageInfo`.

Also, you will need to change your form model attribute to `model = OpsPageInfo` rather than `model = ops_page`

Answer (score 3):

Fixed a similar problem where a view was named exactly the same as a model. Just spent half an hour on it. Thought it could help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this, was trying to `import my_project.models`

but had a file within `my_project` called `my_project.py`

So python was trying to do `my_project.models` from `my_project.py` instead of `my_project`(direcory)

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score -1):

You need to prefix forms and models in your import with a . (period) or the name of the app (not recommended since then you'd be hard coding the name of the app into your project when you don't need too).

so change:

```
from forms import OpsPageForm
```

to

```
from .forms import OpsPageForm
```

and change:

```
from models import OpsPageInfo
```

to:

```
from .models import OpsPageInfo
```